# Docstring style for unknown class attribute?

Tags: python, docstring

I have a class that is going to parse a database and create n number of attributes, where each attribute is a NumPy array of the data in the database, and the name of that attribute is the variable name in the database. The class has an argument (`srqs`) which is a list of strings, where each string is the variable name to extract from the database.

How should I do my docstrings to denote that the valid variable names in `srqs` will become attributes of an instances of the class?

```
class DataBase(object):
    """Creates an instance of the database and the requested srqs
    Attributes:
        dbname (str): Database filename to use.
        ???
    """

    def __init__(self, dbname=None, srqs=None):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.extract_data()

    def extract_data(self):
        with OpenDB(self.dbname) as db:
            for srq in srqs:
                db.__dict__[srq] = db.GetData(srq)

>>>foo = DataBase('/usr/bin/testdb.bar', ['s1', 's2', 'T'])
>>>foo.__dict__
{'dbname': '/usr/bin/testdb.bar', 's1': np.array([0,0,0]), ...}
```

Comment: If you don't have an automated tool that processes docstrings and requires a special syntax, you are completely free what you write into it and how the text is formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (it basically takes the last sentence of your question, I think you put it pretty well):

```
class DataBase(object):
    """Creates an instance of the database and the requested srqs
    Attributes:
        dbname (str): Database filename in use.
    """

    def __init__(self, dbname=None, srqs=None):
        """
            Arguments:
            dbname (str): Database filename to use.
            srqs (sequence): Valid variable names in srqs will become attributes of an instance of the class
        """
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.extract_data()
```

Comment: The docstring being on the class would indicate class attributes rather than instance attributes.  If the docstring is in \_\_init\_\_, this answer seems sensible to me.